# Async recursive function for iterating over a B-Tree causes "Cannot resolve opaque type" in Rust

Tags: recursion, rust, async-await, rust-tokio

I'm trying to create a function that iterates over the elements of a B-Tree, in order. Accessing the children in my B-Tree is an async operation, so the function should return a [`AsyncStream`](https://tokio.rs/tokio/tutorial/streams). I'm using the [`async_stream` macro](https://docs.rs/async-stream/latest/async_stream/#) to create the stream, along with `tokio` and [`tokio_stream`](https://docs.rs/tokio-stream/latest/tokio_stream/) for traits.

Here is a minimal failing example:

```rust
use async_stream::stream;
use std::sync::Arc;
use tokio::sync::RwLock;
use tokio_stream::{Stream, StreamExt};

struct Node {
    keys: Vec<usize>,
    children: Vec<Arc<RwLock<Node>>>,
}

impl Node {
    fn new(keys: Vec<usize>, children: Vec<Arc<RwLock<Node>>>) -> Arc<RwLock<Self>> {
        Arc::new(RwLock::new(Node { keys, children }))
    }
    async fn get_child(&self, index: usize) -> Option<Arc<RwLock<Node>>> {
        self.children.get(index).cloned()
    }
}

fn traverse(node: Arc<RwLock<Node>>) -> impl Stream<Item = usize> {
    stream! {
        let n_keys = node.read().await.keys.len();
        for i in 0..n_keys {
            yield node.read().await.keys[i].clone();
            if let Some(child) = node.read().await.get_child(i).await {
                let child_stream = traverse(child);
                tokio::pin!(child_stream);
                while let Some(k) = child_stream.next().await {
                    yield k
                }
            }
        }
        // last child
        if let Some(child) = node.read().await.get_child(n_keys).await {
            let child_stream = traverse(child);
            tokio::pin!(child_stream);
            while let Some(k) = child_stream.next().await {
                yield k
            }
        }

    }
}

#[tokio::test]
async fn t() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let root = Node::new(
        vec![3],
        vec![Node::new(vec![1], vec![]), Node::new(vec![5], vec![])],
    );
    let mut result = vec![];
    let stream = traverse(root);
    tokio::pin!(stream);
    while let Some(k) = stream.next().await {
        result.push(k);
    }
    assert_eq!(result, vec![1, 3, 5]);
    Ok(())
}
```

My limited understanding of the problem is that `-> impl Stream<...>` is an "[opaque type](https://rustc-dev-guide.rust-lang.org/opaque-types-type-alias-impl-trait.html)" and the compiler cannot infer the concrete type because of recursion. So I get this error:

```
error[E0720]: cannot resolve opaque type
   --> tests/streamq.rs:20:41
    |
15  |       async fn get_child(&self, index: usize) -> Option<Arc<RwLock<Node>>> {
    |                                                  ------------------------- returning this type `AsyncStream<usize, [async block@/home/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/async-stream-0.3.5/src/lib.rs:193:9: 193:59]>`
...
20  |   fn traverse(node: Arc<RwLock<Node>>) -> impl Stream<Item = usize> {
    |                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ recursive opaque type
21  | /     stream! {
22  | |         let n_keys = node.read().await.keys.len();
23  | |         for i in 0..n_keys {
24  | |             yield node.read().await.keys[i].clone();
25  | |             if let Some(child) = node.read().await.get_child(i).await {
26  | |                 let child_stream = traverse(child);
    | |                     ------------ async closure captures itself here
27  | |                 tokio::pin!(child_stream);
    | |                 ------------------------- async closure captures itself here
28  | |                 while let Some(k) = child_stream.next().await {
    | |                                     -------------------
    | |                                     |
    | |                                     async closure captures itself here
    | |                                     async closure captures itself here
...   |
41  | |
42  | |     }
    | |     -
    | |_____|
    | |_____returning here with type `AsyncStream<usize, [async block@/home/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/async-stream-0.3.5/src/lib.rs:193:9: 193:59]>`
    | |_____returning here with type `AsyncStream<usize, [async block@/home/g.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/async-stream-0.3.5/src/lib.rs:193:9: 193:59]>`
    | |_____returning here with type `AsyncStream<usize, [async block@/home/g.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/async-stream-0.3.5/src/lib.rs:193:9: 193:59]>`
    | |_____returning here with type `AsyncStream<usize, [async block@/home/g.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/async-stream-0.3.5/src/lib.rs:193:9: 193:59]>`
    | |_____returning here with type `AsyncStream<usize, [async block@/home/g.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/async-stream-0.3.5/src/lib.rs:193:9: 193:59]>`
    | |_____returning here with type `AsyncStream<usize, [async block@/home/g.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/async-stream-0.3.5/src/lib.rs:193:9: 193:59]>`
    |       returning here with type `AsyncStream<usize, [async block@/home/g.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/async-stream-0.3.5/src/lib.rs:193:9: 193:59]>`
    |
   ::: /home/g.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/tokio-1.34.0/src/sync/rwlock.rs:430:33
    |
430 |       pub async fn read(&self) -> RwLockReadGuard<'_, T> {
    |                                   ---------------------- returning this type `AsyncStream<usize, [async block@/home/g.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/async-stream-0.3.5/src/lib.rs:193:9: 193:59]>`
    |
   ::: /home/g.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/async-stream-0.3.5/src/yielder.rs:42:41
    |
42  |       pub fn send(&mut self, value: T) -> impl Future<Output = ()> {
    |                                           ------------------------ returning this type `AsyncStream<usize, [async block@/home/g.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/async-stream-0.3.5/src/lib.rs:193:9: 193:59]>`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0720`.
error: could not compile `` (test "streamq") due to previous error
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
```

Is there a way to work around this without having to manually implement the [`Stream` trait](https://docs.rs/futures-core/0.3.29/futures_core/stream/trait.Stream.html)?